# How can I rewrite my url to a shorter url in IIS?

Tags: iis, rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a url from a longer url to shorter url. I want

`https://contrivedexample.com/favorite-movie/add?id=7&name=pointbreak`

to rewrite to

`https://contrivedexample.com?id=7&name=ohaimark`

as that's the route I currently support until I have proper client-side routing.

In my web.config, I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite Long Url" >
                    <match url="^/favorite-movie/add" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your rules this way:

```
<match url="^favorite-movie/add(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

I think this should work.